# Python - Need help reading txt file

Tags: python, python-3.9, pycord

Ok, so im trying to make a discord bot that says joke, i have all the joke stored in a txt file that users can add to and get jokes from using .addjoke and .joke commands. However when making a command that removes jokes(a line from the file), the code doesnt read the whole file and instead reads the last line, which has nothing written.

```
@client.command()
async def clearjoke(ctx, l=1):
    with open(working_directory / 'txt files/Jokes.txt', 'r') as jokes:
        jokes.seek(0)
        lines = jokes.readlines()
        file = jokes.read()
        print(file)

    jokes.close()

await ctx.send(f'Joke Removed on Line {l}!')
```

Comment: Of course.  You read all the lines into `lines`.  At that point, you are positioned at the end of the file, so `jokes.read()` reads nothing.    Since you have all the lines as a convenient list in `lines` already, what's the point of reading any more?

Comment: You read all the content with `jokes.readlines()`. What do you hope to read with the following `jokes.read()`? BTW, you really don't need `jokes.seek(0)`. And you don't need `jokes.close()` since you used `with open ...` to open the file.